# MacBook Unidentified Sound

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook started making a weird sound a few weeks ago. It happens about every 10 minutes, and I don't know what is causing it. It's not the hardware. I know because if my computer is on mute, then I can't hear it. Here is a link to a video that plays the sound: ﻿https://youtu.be/nCEbk7zI3cs

I'm on a 2017 MacBook Pro running High Sierra.

How can I get this sound to go away?

Comment: Do you have a USB drive (or any other peripheral) plugged in?

Comment: sounds like my email notification

Comment: go to /System/Library/Sounds/ and play for example the Tink.aiff ...does it sounds like that

Comment: I had something like this and found that I had accidentally set a chime for every half hour. Check your notifications, alarms and clock.

Comment: I don't have any peripherals plugged in. I don't get any notifications when it happens. I played through all of the sounds in /System/Library/Sounds/ and it wasn't any of them. I don't think I have any alarms set. I have "Announce the time" disabled in settings.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my OS version to Mojave, and it went away. I still have no idea what it was, but at least it's gone.